# fatal error: file massage.h not found

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cloned package from git repository. After that I tried to make it with catkin, but it fails. Firstly I use my package in groovy, but robot is on hydro. Maybe it makes any difference. This is an output of catkin_make:

```
Base path: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.77
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - rop_client
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rop_client'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rop_client)
-- rop_client: 3 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  6%] Building CXX object rop_client/CMakeFiles/event_grabber.dir/src/start_event_grabber.cpp.o
In file included from /home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/src/rop_client/src/start_event_grabber.cpp:1:0:
/home/turtlebot2/catkin_ws/src/rop_client/src/event_grabber.h:7:31: fatal error: rop_client/RopInt.h: No such file or directory
компиляция прервана.
make[2]: *** [rop_client/CMakeFiles/event_grabber.dir/src/start_event_grabber.cpp.o] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [rop_client/CMakeFiles/event_grabber.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
make: INTERNAL: Exiting with 3 jobserver tokens available; should be 2!
Invoking "make" failed
```

I checked catkin_ws/devel/include/ path, but there are no generated .h files. What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111136/fatal-error:-file-massage.h-not-found/) by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that the message is part of your package. You need to add a dependency from your library/executable target to the target which performs the message generation.

Please see at the bottom of this documentation: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/building_msgs.html

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2013-12-18**:
Thank you, it works!

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-16**:
I found this question while looking to solve a similar issue, note that Dirk's link is now broken.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-16**:
http://docs.ros.org/api/genmsg/html/usermacros.html is probably the updated link.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve my problem by proceeding command "make" in path "build" with parameters -j4 -l4. But Dirk Tomas gave much more precise answer.

---

Originally posted by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) with karma: 47 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-19**:
This only "solves" the symptom for you but not the actual problem. Depending on timing and random target order it might fail some times and might need to be run multiple times.